# refresh form with change in select option

Tags: ajax, laravel, model-view-controller

So I want to refresh the update form with the change in the select option (which will be year).

This is my form:

```
         <select class="form-control" id="year_select" name="year_select">
            @foreach($pickyear as $key=>$unique) 
                <option value= "{!! $unique !!}"> {!! $unique !!} </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>

    {!! Form::open(['url' => 'form', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']) !!}
        //form is included here
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

So I want to reload or refresh the form with every change in select value or ajax call.

Ajax call:

```
 $('select[name="year_select" ]).change(function(e) {
        // e.preventDefault();
        const year = $(this).val();
        window.location.reload();
        const url = `/form/${year}`;    

        $.ajax({
            url,
            type: 'PUT',
            success: function(res) {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
    })
```

Edit: Refreshing / reloading whole page would do too.

Update:  The imput parameter should be updatable and should change value according to the year from select option.

[image]

Comment: Please add some more context to your question. Would you mind adding image of your form for more clarity?

Comment: I have attached screenshot of sample form. Hope it helps you understand better.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onchange="this.form.submit()"` for page reload when Select Option change

on blade

```php
<select name="year_select" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    @foreach($pickyear as $key=>$unique) 
        <option value= "{!! $unique !!}"> {!! $unique !!} </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

now url should be `form_url?year_select=2022` and you can filter data from controller

On controller

```php
$model = Model::query();

if (request('year_select')) {
    $model->whereYear('your_year_column', request('year_select'));
} 
// else
// {
//     // if you need current year as default
//     $model->whereYear('your_year_column', date('Y'));
// }

$data = $model->get();
```